# If I know there is only gonna be one element with that name (XML(PHP DOM)), how can I select it?

Tags: php, xml, dom, getelementsbytagname

I am trying to add some data received from a form to an XML file which already exists. I am using DOMDocument in PHP for adding the data to the file...

While I am somewhat successful in adding the data, it is adding into the wrong element.

Now I know there is only gonna be one element with a certain name, which will be the root element. I also know that there is gonna be only one element with a name which will contain other data.

Those elements don't have an ID and I want to read them by `getElementsByTagName` in PHP using DOMDocument.

So if i know that there is gonna be only one element with that name in the whole file, then can i do something like this:

`$element = $dom->getElementByTagName('ElementName'); $element[0];`

I mean can I select only the first element in the array? And how should I do it? Because the code above doesn't work.

Comment: Which DOM library? DOMDocument? SimpleXML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TagName refers to the name of the html or xml tag. If there is only one you should be able to do something like this:

```
$element = $dom->getElementByTagName('ElementName')->item(0);
```

However it sounds like what you are really looking for can be done with xpath:

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$elements = $xpath->query("//*[@name='ElementName']");

foreach ($elements as $node)
{
    $element[] = $node;
}
```

Now $element[0] should be the element you are looking for.

Comment: Arjun is not looking at `name` attributes, and why bother building an array when working with the DOMNodeList is easy?

Answer (score 2):

The return value from `getElementsByTagName()` is a `DOMNodeList` object, which is *not* an array.  Access to individual items in the list is via the `item()` method.

```
$element = $dom->getElementByTagName('ElementName')->item(0);
```

See:

- http://php.net/domdocument.getelementsbytagname
- http://php.net/domnodelist
- http://php.net/domnodelist.item

Comment: ok cool, thanks... now i even know about the item() method... thanks... :D